# SSRS report generates extra data

Tags: ssrs-2012

I used SSRS to generate report using excel as a DataSource. Report should be only of 27 pages but I am getting 32 pages. Is there any thing that generates these extra data?

Comment: Why are you only expecting 27 pages?  What is on the 32 pages?  More detail is needed to allow us to help with this question, such as sample data, current output and desired output